# matching files with regular expressions

Tags: bash, sed, awk, gawk

I have an input file with a list of movies (Note that there might be some repeated entries):

```
American_beauty__1h56mn38s_
As_Good_As_It_Gets
As_Good_As_It_Gets
_DivX-ITA__Casablanca_M_CURTIZ_1942_Bogart-bergman_
Capote_EN_DVDRiP_XViD-GeT-AW
_DivX-ITA__Casablanca_M_CURTIZ_1942_Bogart-bergman_
```

I would to find the corresponding match (line number) from another
reference file for each of the entries in the first file:

```
American beauty.(1h56mn38s)
As Good As It Gets
Capote.EN.DVDRiP.XViD-GeT-AW
[DivX-ITA] Casablanca(M.CURTIZ 1942 Bogart-bergman)
Quills (2000)(7.4)
```

The desired output would be something like (Reference Movie + Line number from the Reference File):

```
American beauty.(1h56mn38s) 1
As Good As It Gets 2
As Good As It Gets 2
[DivX-ITA] Casablanca(M.CURTIZ 1942 Bogart-bergman) 4
Capote.EN.DVDRiP.XViD-GeT-AW 3
[DivX-ITA] Casablanca(M.CURTIZ 1942 Bogart-bergman) 4
```

Basically, the difference between the entries in both files is that some characters such as: blank spaces, parenthesis, points, etc. have been replaced by underscores.

Does anybody could shed some light on it?

Best wishes,

Javier

Answer (score 1):

Awk will work:

```
gawk '
  NR == FNR {
    # read the reference file first, capture the line numbers and transform
    # the "real" title to one with underscores
    line[$0] = NR
    u = $0
    gsub(/[][ .()]/,"_",u)
    movie[u] = $0
    next
  }
  $0 in movie {
    print movie[$0] " " line[movie[$0]]
  }
' movies.reference movies.list
```

The regular expression could be simplified if hyphens were also turned into underscores (would be `/\W/` then).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just strip all the non-desired characters (from both the file listing and textfile) using sed?

e.g

```
ls | sed -e 's/[^a-z0-9]/o/gi'
```

Or if you want more fuzziness, you could try to do some least editing distance on the processed filename (or a tokenized version).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It won't be particularly fast:

```
#!/bin/bash
chars='[]() .'
num=0
while read -r line
do
    (( num++ ))
    num=$( grep --line-number "$line" <( tr "$chars" '_' < movies.reference ) | awk -F: '{print $1}' )
    echo "$( sed -n "$num{p;q}" movies.reference ) $num"
done < movies.input
```